# Sharepoint 2010 to o365 Migration issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

When we are migrating a workspace to SharePoint o365 using Sharegate,
There are few issues that i encountered
1. Meeting Dates are missing from left refinement panel.

2. Under Attendees webpart its displaying "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID:d05eed9d-50ac-3000-012d-3281499bca8f"

3. under Document library webpart content are displaying where as in SP 2010 no contents are displayed.

Is this because SharePoint online does not have workspace template?
how can we solve these issue?

Comment: Its causing issues because meeting workspace template is not supported after 2010. It breaks even if you migrate from 2010 to 2013 on prem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, is there Any solution to fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for Sharegate :) What I'd suggest is contacting Support directly (support@share-gate.com) so they can help you directly by checking the Migration Report with you.

You can also take a look at this doc article, it might give you the answer you're looking for. https://support.share-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000647388-Does-Sharegate-support-Meeting-Workspaces-

Good luck!

Comment: Thank Mia, I could solve 2nd and 3rd issue but 1st is still remaining, how can we get the Meeting Dates in the left refinement panel?

Comment: hi Mia
There is one more question related to migration as below, can you plz help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781271/sharepoint-2010-migration-to-sharepoint-online-using-sharegate

Comment: Hi again! Unfortunately, it is not supported because of a SharePoint limitation. In a meeting workspace, the refinement panel is configured to use the creation date of the site. So, it works when you create it the first time, but when you go to migrate, Sharegate recreates the site and the date changes. Hope this helps!