# Sharepoint 2010 migration to sharepoint online using sharegate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

We have migrated few surveys from 2010 to SharePoint o365,
but we observed that there is a change in Time created of the survey
as below
in SP 2010
Time Created: 7/17/2014 6:21 AM

and in SP online
Time Created:   4/29/2017 8:51 PM

is this a limitation of share gate that it cannot retain the time created or there is something wrong with the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the creation date of each survey answer or the creation date of the survey list itself?

For each answer, Sharegate should have copied the correct values for Created By/Modified By/Created/Modified.

For the list itself, it is a limitation of SharePoint / O365 where the "creation date" cannot be forced to anything other than the actual creation date. Sharegate (or any other tool or script) can't put a custom value in there.

Comment: Thank you this helps, i was exactly talking about the creation date of the list itself.